# React native swipe animation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, swipe

[image]
I want to make above screen in which i need to add swipe animation. when user swipe right then swipe button moves to right and come back to center.when user swipes left then button moves to left and come back to center position with animation.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've used react native swipe gestures to get where user swipes but i need to add animations for which i am looking for?